# Probably some obvious mistake in java I've made which I can't find (java)

Tags: java

I just started using Java yesterday. I've tried researching but didn't find anything I could make use of. The problem is that no matter what I type as an Input the program always outputs "Hell" and "Hello fmdas". I think I should write the `if (BetOrPlay != "Bet");` Line as `else if (BetOrPlay != "Bet");`
But the program doesn't allow me to do that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MoneyMaker
{

    static Scanner Choice = new Scanner (System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Do you want to bet your coins or earn more by playing this game?");
        try
        {

            if (Choice.hasNextLine())
            {
                String BetOrPlay = Choice.nextLine();
                if (BetOrPlay == "Bet");
                {
                    System.out.println("Hell");
                }
                if (BetOrPlay != "Bet");
                {
                    System.out.println("Hello fmdas");  
                }       
            }   
        }
        finally
        {
            Choice.close();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Use .equals() to compare Strings as the marked duplicate shows. Also, putting semicolon (;) after if statement, makes the if statement useless.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually do anything under the if blocks.

```
  if (BetOrPlay == "Bet"); //remove ; here
  if (BetOrPlay != "Bet"); //remove ; here
```